# Setting to change monitoring graph Y-axis to start from 0 in google cloud monitoring

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-monitoring

In google cloud monitoring the graph's Y-axis range is dynamic.

[image: graphs]

In this graphs you can see the CPU y-axis starts from 0 while the memory Y-axis starts from 4GB. The lower bound keeps on changing. This is problematic from a monitoring perspective as on a quick glance it would give the perspective that approx. 50% is being used unless someone notices the Y-axis bounds. I would prefer having all graphs start from 0 (irrespective of units). I cannot find any option to do that. Am I missing something here or did google cloud not add this basic functionality yet?

Answer (score 3):

When you're in a dashboard displaying chart, click on the three dots in the top-right corner and select "stats mode".

That will change the Y-axis to start from 0.

[image]

Comment: I am monitoring kubernetes used, requested and limits for pods. If I choose stats mode then the lines change and the graph become meaningless as it shows stats of these three which does not make any sense from a monitoring perspective. So this is not a solution.

Comment: I tried it for memory usage. In your case it might have worked because one of the stats was close to zero.  This solution is not working in case all stats are much larger than 0

Comment: In this case there's nothing that can be done - you can however request this feature in [Google IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) and describe in detail what do you need and how do you expect it to work. Please also refer to this thread when raising a new issue.